# How to avoid Error "There is already an open DataReader associated with this Command" in MSSql 2000

Tags: sql-server-2000, sqlbulkcopy, datareader

I am using SqlBulkCopy to copy data to 2 separate table in same database.

```
obj_Command.CommandText = "Select * from  tmpInvDtlMast where InvNo='111'"



Using bulkCopy As SqlBulkCopy = New SqlBulkCopy(con1)
                        bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "tmpInvDtlMast"

                        Try

                            bulkCopy.WriteToServer(obj_Command.ExecuteReader())
                            Application.DoEvents()

                        Catch ex As Exception
                            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message)
                        Finally
                            bulkCopy.Close()

                        End Try
                    End Using


                        Using bulkCopy As SqlBulkCopy = New SqlBulkCopy(con1)
                            bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "InvDtlMast"

                            Try

                                bulkCopy.WriteToServer(obj_Command.ExecuteReader())
                                Application.DoEvents()

                            Catch ex As Exception
                                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message)
                            Finally
                                bulkCopy.Close()
                            End Try
                        End Using
```

In the second Bulk upload this error occurs

> There is already an open DataReader associated with this Command

I have tried "MultipleActiveResultSets=true" with my connection string

```
con1.ConnectionString = "Data Source=" & SqlServer & ";Initial Catalog=" & Database & ";Persist Security Info=True;User ID=" & User & ";Password=" & Pass & ";MultipleActiveResultSets=true"
```

After googling more solutions I got to know that MultipleActiveResultSets=true not support for MSSql 2000. Is there anything to do to solve this in Sql2000. Please help

Im using vb.net 2008

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved my problem myslf. What I did is remove

> obj_Command.ExecuteReader()

with new SqlDataReader instance.

```
obj_Command.CommandText = "Select * from  tmpInvDtlMast where InvNo='111'"
Dim dr as SqlDataReader()
dr=obj_Command.ExecuteNoneQuery()

               Using bulkCopy As SqlBulkCopy = New SqlBulkCopy(con1)
                    bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "tmpInvDtlMast"

                    Try

                        bulkCopy.WriteToServer(dr)
                        Application.DoEvents()

                    Catch ex As Exception
                        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message)
                    Finally
                        dr.Close()

                    End Try
                End Using


                    Using bulkCopy As SqlBulkCopy = New SqlBulkCopy(con1)
                        bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "InvDtlMast"

                        Try

                            bulkCopy.WriteToServer(dr)
                            Application.DoEvents()

                        Catch ex As Exception
                            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message)
                        Finally
                            dr.Close()
                        End Try
                    End Using
```

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround try duplicating connection and command:

```
obj_Command.CommandText = "Select * from  tmpInvDtlMast where InvNo='111'"

Using bulkCopy As SqlBulkCopy = New SqlBulkCopy(con1)
    bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "tmpInvDtlMast"

    Try
        bulkCopy.WriteToServer(obj_Command.ExecuteReader())
        Application.DoEvents()

    Catch ex As Exception
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message)
    Finally
        bulkCopy.Close()

    End Try
End Using


Using bulkCopy As SqlBulkCopy = New SqlBulkCopy(**con2**)
    bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "InvDtlMast"

    Try
        bulkCopy.WriteToServer(**obj_Command2**.ExecuteReader())
        Application.DoEvents()

    Catch ex As Exception
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message)
    Finally
        bulkCopy.Close()
    End Try
End Using
```

Comment: @SajithaRathnayake please share your solution